# Segmentation fault after main exit

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, segment-tree

I Have tried executing the following code in gdb, but with gdb I don`t see any segmentation fault but without gdb If I run the following code in standalone mode segmentation fault occurs. The code is related to range sum query implemented using segment tree.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class segmentTree
{
    private:
        vector<int> a;
        void constructUtil(vector<int>& , int , int , int );
        int queryUtil(int , int , int , int , int );
        void updateUtil(int , int , int , int , int );
    public:
        segmentTree(vector<int> );
        int query(int , int );
        void update(int , int );
        ~segmentTree();
};

segmentTree::segmentTree(vector<int> v)
{
    int n = v.size();
    a.resize((2*n) - 1);
    constructUtil(v, 0 , n - 1, 0);
}

segmentTree::~segmentTree()
{
    a.clear();
}

void segmentTree::constructUtil(vector<int>& v, int start, int end, int i)
{
    if(start == end)
    {
        a[i] = v[start];
    }
    else
    {
        int mid = start + ((end - start) >> 1);
        constructUtil(v, start, mid, ((2*i) + 1));
        constructUtil(v, mid + 1, end, ((2*i) + 2));
        a[i] = a[(2*i) + 1] + a[(2*i) + 2];
    }
}

int segmentTree::queryUtil(int ss, int se, int rs, int re, int i)
{
    if(se < rs || re < ss)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(rs <= ss && se <= re)
    {
        return  a[i];
    }
    else
    {
        int sm = ss + ((se - ss) >> 1);
        return queryUtil(ss, sm, rs, re, 2*i + 1) + queryUtil(sm + 1, se, rs, re, 2*i + 2);
    }
}

int segmentTree::query(int l, int r)
{
    int n = ((a.size() + 1) >> 1);
    if(l < 0 || r > n-1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return queryUtil(0, n-1, l , r, 0);
}

void segmentTree::updateUtil(int ss, int se, int i, int si, int x)
{
    if(ss > i || se < i)
    {
        return ;
    }
    else if(ss == se)
    {
        a[si] = x;
    }
    else
    {
        int sm = ss + ((se - ss) >> 1);
        updateUtil(ss, sm, i, (2*si) + 1, x);
        updateUtil(sm + 1, se, i, (2*si) + 2, x);
        a[si] = a[(2*si) + 1] + a[(2*si) + 2];
    }
}

void segmentTree::update(int i, int x)
{
    int n = ((a.size() + 1) >> 1);
    if(i < 0 || i > n-1)
    {
        return ;
    }
    else
    {
        updateUtil(0, n-1, i, 0, x);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    vector<int> v(arr, arr + n);

    segmentTree st(v);

    // Print sum of values in array from index 1 to 3
    cout << "Sum of values in given range = " << st.query(1, 3) << endl;

    // Update: set arr[1] = 10 and update corresponding 
    // segment tree nodes
    st.update(1, 10);

    // Find sum after the value is updated
    cout << "Updated sum of values in given range = " << st.query(1, 3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Notice that the OP notes that the segfault only occurs when he is **NOT** using a debugger.

Comment: @TimSeguine Must be undefined behavior then.

Comment: If you have the ability to compile this with AddressSanitizer turned on, it will probably be able to tell you the exact line where you are doing something wrong next time it segfaults.

Comment: Can't reproduce [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41484569e6b7f109) which makes UB likely.  I would change all of your `vector_name[index]` calls to `vector_name.at(index)` and see if you get an exception thrown.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ pretty much by definition

Answer (score 1):

Consider `segmentTree::constructUtil` with `v.size() == 3`. Then in the inital call to `constructUtil` you have `start == 0` and `end == 2`.

Thus we get `mid = 1`.

In the second recursive call we are then passing `start = 1`, `end = 2` and `i = 2`. `start != end` and so the `else` is executed.

However in the `else` block `a[(2*i)+2]` is accessed (by the way, no need for the parantheses there). This index will be `6`.

But if you look at the size of `a`, it was given as `2*n-1`. `2*3-1 = 5`, so `6` is clearly out-of-bounds.

I don't know what your intentions with the code are, but that there is undefined behavior. You can easily catch it by either using something like valgrind, by replacing `a[...]` with `a.at(...)` for debug purposes, by stepping through the code with gdb and actually following all the variables (there does not need to be a segmentation fault for your program to have undefined behavior) or by entering debug `std::cout` statements with the variable content everywhere that could cause the issue.